# Gitlab run every branch as docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are currently working with 2 environments: `staging` and `production`. For development purposes we would like to run more environments to be able to test better. We have a classic Java Spring backend providing the API for up to 3 different clients. One of these clients is the React frontend which lives in the same repository.

My ideal solution would be something like: Run a docker-compose file (consisting of the backend, a database, react-frontend and a proxy) for each branch.

Is that even feasible? Does it make sense to run each branch or would this lead to a lot of computing time being wasted?
What are some other approaches?

The easiest - but not so scalable - solution would be to just add another `development` environment. But in my opinion it would be great to be able to test the exact configuration before a merge request. We are only 5 developers, so maybe that solution is a bit over the top?